# Using aria attributes on elements in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following render method:

```
render: function () {
  return (
    React.createElement('div', {className: 'modal', id: 'errorModal', tabIndex: '-1', role: 'dialog', ariaHidden: 'true', dataBackdrop: 'false', style: {marginTop: '30px'}}, 'text')
  )
}
```

That gives me error:

> react.js:20541 Warning: Unknown props `ariaHidden`, `dataBackdrop` on
>    tag. Remove these props from the element. For details, see
>       in div (created by Constructor)
>       in Constructor

How could I solve this? Documentation says that I can use these attributes. Lowercase does not work either. I don't want to use jsx.

Comment: try `'aria-hidden'` instead of `ariaHidden`

Comment: Likewise use `data-backdrop` instead of `dataBackdrop`. Data attributes have to start with the `data-` prefix for React to pass them through.

Comment: It seems perverse for React to issue warnings against hyphenated prop names, and in other cases warn against camel-cased prop names! Why not be consistent and require ariaHidden etc?

Answer (score 9):

Instead of camel case, use hyphens to define `aria` attributes as described [in React's docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/accessibility.html#wai-aria):

```
render: function () {
  return (
    React.createElement('div', {className: 'modal', id: 'errorModal', tabIndex: '-1', role: 'dialog', 'aria-hidden': 'true', dataBackdrop: 'false', style: {marginTop: '30px'}}, 'text')
  )
}
```